# Positioning being broken when zoomed out

Tags: html, css

Recently we've had some customers complain about our website positioning being messed up and we've since found out that this problem only occurs when their browser is zoomed out to around the 75% mark. Most of our customers do not realise that their browsers are set to zoomed out mode, and we have been told to fix the problem so positioning is consistent regardless of the zoom level.

I have tried resizing elements using `em` and also tried in `%` but the positioning still messes up.

Here is a link to the website:
http://www.comms-express.com

The issue occurs on all pages - the 'Need Assistance' box at the top right of the page falls off at 75% zoom, and the main boxes on product pages do not fit in the container at 75% zoom.

Could anyone give me some pointers? I'm looking for some kind of CSS media query which would allow me to change CSS rules on specific zoom levels.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem by modifying widths of elements to use percentages instead of pixels, and by re-tweaking how elements were spaced. Instead of using a margin, I placed a smaller inner container and gave this a padding which generally resolved most problems.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to mainly be effecting your `.product` elements, change their width from its current setting of `190.5px;` to 23% so they scale proportionately.

```
.product {
   width: 23%;
}
```

This is likely more of a quick fix than anything else, but should solve the position issue until a more permanent solution is found.